# Touchpad 2 finger scroll ends with a right click, text marking lag

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

Some recent update made my two-finger scrolling unbearable. Every single time I scroll it ends with a right click.

Another thing I've noticed is a sort of lag when I'm marking text. This is also really annoying when you use your computer for work. It's like the left click has a delay of a second when you try to mark something to copy etc.

Comment: Am having the same problem, pretty annoying. Adding a bounty.

Comment: This may or may not help, but have you checked the Additional Drivers program for a proprietary driver for your touchpad?

Comment: @dafish728 nothing there :-\ Also, the last couple days it suddenly stopped happening...

Comment: You might want to check this answer to a similar problem : http://askubuntu.com/questions/657258/chrome-two-finger-scroll-then-right-clicks

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Comment: Pasting this into Terminal elicits a, "command not found" error...