# Chrome two finger scroll then right clicks

Tags: 15.04, google-chrome, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I am having problems with my touchpad in Chrome.  Whenever I two finger scroll for a short time (~< 1 second, I think, its hard to time) I then get shown the right click menu.  If I keep my fingers on the touchpad for longer, even if I don't scroll, then no right click occurs.

As you can imagine this is high frustrating as 1s is surprisingly long in terms of scroll time and finding myself right clicking every scroll is incredibly annoying.

System details:

- Dell XPS13 2015
- Ubuntu Gnome 15.04
- 3.19.0-25-generic
- Chrome Version 45.0.2454.15 beta (64-bit)

Comment: Two-finger tap is right click. You probably tap too fast to scroll. It is possible to disable that or change tap timing.

Comment: Is this happening only on Chrome ?

Comment: I have only noticed it in Chrome so far.  Which makes it seem even odder.

Comment: Happening here too. I notice that if you let the scroll-action stop, THEN take your fingers off the touchpad, there's no right click. It only happens if you take your fingers off the touchpad while Chrome is still scrolling. I use the wheel-smooth-scroll extension, so I wondered if that was related... but disabling it does nothing.

Comment: You've discovered a known bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1454473 contains more information and workarounds.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue only in Chrome too.
You can solve this problem by using `50-synaptics.conf` config file :

```
wget http://hgdev.co/wp-content/uploads/50-synaptics.conf
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
sudo cp 50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

You can also manually edit this config file to better fits your preferences. The [Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics) on Synatics trackpad will be helpful for this.

Comment: I've added this now and everything seems to be working, but since rebooting fixed the issue anyway, I'll have to wait a couple of days before I know for sure. How on earth did you find this solution??

Comment: I kind of accidentally found this solution. I used this config file for a long time (to enable three fingers click etc...). After a fresh Ubuntu install (without this conf file) I noticed this bug in Chromium. But with the config file, no problem  (despite I am not sure which exact  option fix the problem...)

Comment: Well, it's been about two weeks and I haven't seen a repeat of this behaviour. Seems fixed for me. The sensitivities in this fix are a little different to what I'm used to, and it kills my "right click by clicking on the right of the touchpad", but adds two-finger click for right click, so not the end of the world. All looking good.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the two-finger-scrolling issue by following these steps:

- Open a terminal (shell) window.
- Run the command below in order to become root (superuser). Becoming root is important because **ALL** the shell commands below have to be performed by the **superuser** (all but this first one, obviously):

  ```
  sudo su
  ```
- Run the command below in order to download the standard Linux touchpad configuration file **50-synaptics.conf**:

  ```
  wget http://hgdev.co/wp-content/uploads/50-synaptics.conf
  ```
- Run the command below in order to create the folder **xorg.conf.d** inside of **/etc/X11/**:

  ```
  mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
  ```
- Now run the command below in order to move the configuration file **50-synaptics.conf** into **/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/**:

  ```
  mv 50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
  ```
- Restart your computer.

If you're still experiencing any problem with scrolling-then-undiserably-right-clicking in Chrome/Chromium browser (or in any other WebKit/Blink engine browser, or anywhere else), activate **coasting**. When coasting is enabled, scrolling continues for a while after the two fingers are released from the clickpad. The coasting feature causes the Synaptics input driver to stay too busy (unavailable) for a while, thus it won't be able to attempt any unsolicited right click right after you release the clickpad.

- In order to activate coasting, first you have to open a shell terminal window, become root and then run the command below in order to open the configuration file **50-synaptics.conf** for edition (don't forget that you always have to be **root** in order to correctly perform any of these commands):

  ```
  gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
  ```

  - If you don't have Gedit, you can install it with this command:

    ```
    apt-get install gedit
    ```
- Alternatively, if you don't have Gedit but does have Mousepad, just run this command:

  ```
  mousepad /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
  ```

  - Mousepad is a nice Gedit alternative. If you don't have it, I recommend installing it with this command:

    ```
    apt-get install mousepad
    ```
- Coasting is enabled by setting the "CoastingSpeed" parameter to a non-zero number. "CoastingSpeed" sets the minimum scrolls per second you have to perform in order to start coasting. The default is 20, which should prevent you from starting coasting unintentionally. The bigger the number, the harder it becomes to start coasting. 0 disables coasting. Here's the recommended configuration to add to your **50-synaptics.conf** file (right below **Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "8"**, please delete **#Option "CoastingSpeed" "0"** and then paste the text below in its place):

  ```
  # Starts coasting when the user performs 20 scrolls per second (or more):

  Option "CoastingSpeed" "20"

  # Disables corner coasting, thus making coasting available on the entire area of the clickpad (instead of only on the right corner).

  Option "CornerCoasting" "0"
  ```
- Also, add the "CoastingFriction" option. It sets the number of scrolls/second² to be applied in order to decrease the coasting speed until it stops. Default value is 50. The bigger the number, the faster the coasting event will stop:

  ```
  # "CoastingFriction" sets the number of scrolls/second² at which the coasting speed decreases (deceleration) until coasting stops. Default value is 50. The bigger the number, the faster the coasting event will stop.

  Option "CoastingFriction" "50"
  ```
- Now save the file and exit Gedit/Mousepad.
- Restart your computer. Now everything shall be working.

---

The above solution shall be enough if you have a conventional touchpad. However, if you have a **clickpad** (a buttonless touchpad), you may experience a second issue: the two-finger-scrolling issue is solved, but now the **botton right click button emulation** may have stopped working. In such case, you will still be able to use a two-finger tap (it behaves like a right click), but that's it, no more right click by pressing the lower-right corner of your clickpad.

- In order to fix this second issue, go back to the shell terminal window, become root again and use Gedit/Mousepad to open the configuration file **50-synaptics.conf** again for edition, then go to the section where it reads:

  ```
  Identifier "Ignore clickpad buttons"
  MatchDriver "synaptics"
  Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
  ```

  ...and modify the text so it becomes this:

  ```
  Identifier "Enable clickpad buttons"
  MatchDriver "synaptics"
  Option "SoftButtonAreas" "60% 0 82% 0 40% 59% 82% 0"
  ```
- Now save the file and exit Gedit/Mousepad.
- Restart your computer. Now everything shall be working.
- If you still experience any problem with right, middle and/or left button(s), open the shell terminal window again, become root / superuser again, then open **50-synaptics.conf** for edition and make sure the following options are present in the file and that they are configured as shown below:

  ```
  # Interprets 1-finger click/tap as "left button click", 2-fingers click/tap as "right button click" and 3-fingers click/tap as "middle button click":

  Option "TapButton1" "1"
  Option "TapButton2" "3"
  Option "TapButton3" "2"

  Option "ClickFinger1" "1"
  Option "ClickFinger2" "3"
  Option "ClickFinger3" "2"

  # Enables "right button click" in the right botton of the touchpad/clickpad:
  Option "RBCornerButton" "3"
  ```
- Now save the file and exit Gedit/Mousepad.
- Restart your computer. Now everything shall be working.

Comment: Nice work with the right click. Works a treat here on the Dell XPS 13 (2015).

Comment: @Scaine: you're welcome. :) Mine is a Dell Inspiron 5548, still the above solution did the trick. This happens because the configuration parameter **Identifier "XPS13 settings"** isn't really parsed by the Synaptics input driver: "Identifier" exists just so humans can more easily identify what the configuration refers to. The parameters that are actually parsed to identify the driver and the device are respectively "MatchDriver" and "MatchProduct". Hence, you can replace "XPS13 settings" with "My clickpad", "Dell XPS 13 (2015)" or anything else that better fits your taste.  :)

Comment: In case someone prefers to use my **50-synaptics.conf** as a template, I've just uploaded it to my OneDrive. In order to download the file, just follow this link:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E76DDEE650969DF1!1363&authkey=!AEZRL7hpS6OA7lM&ithint=folder%2cconf

Comment: How to test whether Ubuntu is using this conf file and not ignoring it?

Comment: @Imran There are many ways you can do this. E.g.: move the `50-synaptics.conf` file to (e.g.) the `/tmp` folder, restart the computer and test if it changes the (click/touch)pad's behavior. Another way: edit such file and change the `MatchDriver "synaptics"` line `#MatchDriver "synaptics"`, save, reboot and test the pad. Another way: edit the file, change `"TapButton1" "1"` to `"TapButton1" "2"` and `"TapButton3" "2"` to `"TapButton3" "1"`, do the same with `"ClickFinger1"` and `"ClickFinger3"`, save the file, reboot the computer and check if the right and left buttons are swapped/inverted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment :(  Long time lurker, here, but I *just* started having this problem recently.  It only happens in Chrome (but oddly enough, not in Chromium).

**edit**: I'm running the same system as you (XPS 13 2015) and was able to remedy this issue, but only by disabling the Touchscreen.  You can access that by checking `xinput` and doing `xinput disable 10` (or whatever `id` you get for `ELAN Touchscreen`).